# Trouble saving from datepicker to database

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, datepicker, laravel-8

Currently I have a jquery datepicker where it is possible to add a from date and to date. Both of the dates get added from the same input. The format I end up with is this

```
$request->input('datepicker') // 07/29/2022 - 07/30/2022
```

I have a starts_at date in the datebase which is a timestamp

This is how I am trying to change the format before saving it to the database

```
$firstDate = Carbon::parse(strtok($request->input('daterange'), '-'));

$startsAt = Carbon::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $firstDate)->format('y-m-d');
```

The startsAt line is giving me the following error

```
The separation symbol could not be found Unexpected data found. Trailing data
```

If I remove the Carbon::parse() which I thought first was not nessesary the error is instead just

```
Trailing data
```

Caused by the same line

Comment: you're using Postgres?

Comment: @N69S I am using mysql

Comment: Don't know it helps but strtok() function will return "07/29/2022  ". You have a trailing space there.

Answer (score 0):

```
$dates = array_map('trim', explode('-', $request->input('datepicker'))); // return array ['07/29/2022', '07/30/2022'] trim to remove whitespaces at the start and end.
```

Then:

```
$startsAt = Carbon::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $dates[0])->format('y-m-d');
$endsAt = Carbon::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $dates[1])->format('y-m-d');
```

Just you need to be sure that the input is always on that format, so you probably need a validation regexp to ensure that always comes as "m/d/Y - m/d/Y" format